# Error compiling android app after pull

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I started to develop an android app to learn android week ago, and after a deep code refactor to implement clean code architecture i get this comple error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, 

    :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
    /home/kazzzweb/Workspace/android/myrecipesapp/app/build/intermediates/manifests/instant-run/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
    Error:(17, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').
    Error:(17, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    Information:BUILD FAILED
    Information:Total time: 1.933 secs
    Information:3 errors
    Information:0 warnings
    Information:See complete output in console
```

I searched on google and stackoverflow but i didn't found anything, so i'll very greatful if someone can help me :). All the code with last changes is on github: [MyRecipesApp](https://github.com/lucasmenendez/myrecipesapp), and im sure that has many errors so be patient please.

Thanks!

Comment: No resource found , '@mipmap/ic_launcher'

Comment: yep, but this line is generated by android-studio, not by me, if i try to delete it and then rebuild, i get the same error and that line keep in manifest

Comment: Sorry but im stupid, im trying to edit error output. Its just like @PavneetSingh has said. Solved!